# DataFrame Pandas Python select data from date

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = df1[df1['TIME STAMP'].between('2021-01-27 00:00:00', '2021-10-10 23:59:59')]
```

The above code is selecting a dataframe from two specific dates and it works fine.

I want to select a from date and to date (infinity/the last date of dataframe) or any option to select only from date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use comparison operators between timestamps:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = df1[df1['TIME STAMP'] >= pd.Timestamp('2021-01-27 00:00:00')]
```